# Android: Why is click only being heard at top of screen and NOT the assigned view?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, tablelayout, onclicklistener

My app uses programmatically generated TableLayouts that are displayed above a RelativeLayout.  The first row within the TableLayout includes a TextView with an onClickListener assigned.  The TableLayouts are displayed at the BOTTOM of the screen using a TranslateAnimation.  Inexplicably, the clicks are being heard, but only at the TOP of the screen just below the ActionBar.  Plus only one of the listeners is firing.  I must admit I'm baffled about this.  I thought using the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">` would resolve it but no such luck.  Before converting the design to a ListView (which I'd prefer not to have to do) I'm hoping you StackOverflow experts can help sort this out.

Here's a screenshot showing 2 of the generated TableLayouts:
[image: screenshot]

Here's the RelativeLayout parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/GPSTrackerRelativeLayout_root"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/ButtonAndSpinnerRow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_eagleeyeactionbar" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Time_period_select_button"
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android1:layout_gravity="fill_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/selectTimeAndDate"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android1:background="@drawable/petes_custom_click_action_button" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/GPS_unit_select_spinner"
            android:clickable="true" 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/firstDivider"
    style="@style/horizontal_line" />

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    style="@style/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonAndSpinnerRow"
    android:apiKey="MYKEY"
    android:clickable="true" >
 </com.google.android.maps.MapView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the code generating the clickable Button.  The Button is in the second column of the the row.  An image is in the first column.

```
    // Add NAME to 1st row 
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber] = new Button(this); // findViewById(R.id.WatchArea_Name);
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setText("\"" + ControlPanel.pWatchAreaName[GPS_unit_selected][iWatch] + "\" Watch Activity");
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1); // left, top, right, bottom
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setTextSize(HEADER_ROW1_TEXT_SIZE);
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setTextColor(Color.WHITE); // deep blue=parseColor("#00297C")
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); // (Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.LEFT)
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setFocusable(false); 
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setId(GPSTrackerOverlayLayout_ids[overlayNumber]);  //set ID equivalent to parent
      watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setTag(iWatch+ "=|"+ControlPanel.pWatchAreaName[GPS_unit_selected][iWatch]+ "|");
```

`// Add to parent TableRow, then set LayoutParams
    headerRow[overlayNumber].addView(watchAreaName[overlayNumber]);
    TableRow.LayoutParams watchAreaName_layout_params = (TableRow.LayoutParams) watchAreaName[overlayNumber].getLayoutParams();
    watchAreaName_layout_params.column = SECOND_COLUMN; // place in 2nd column
    watchAreaName_layout_params.height = HEADER_ROW1_HEIGHT; // TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    watchAreaName_layout_params.width = 0;  //COLUMN_LABELS_WIDTH;
    watchAreaName_layout_params.weight = (float) .85;
    watchAreaName_layout_params.span = 1; // span this many columns (optional)
    watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setLayoutParams(watchAreaName_layout_params); // 
    watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setBackgroundColor(watchAreaColorIds[watchAreaBackgroundColorSelections[overlayNumber]]); 
    watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setClickable(true);
    watchAreaName[overlayNumber].setOnClickListener(new ShowHideOverlayListener());

 // add finished Header row to TableLayout parent
    GPSTrackerOverlayLayout[overlayNumber].addView(headerRow[overlayNumber], new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TABLE_MATCH_PARENT, TABLE_WRAP_CONTENT)); // width, height
    headerRow[overlayNumber].setFocusable(false);`

Comment: Hmmmm did you set `fillAfter` on the Animation?

Comment: Yes, I did set fillAfter.  I also modifyied the animation so the view slid down starting from half way down the screen instead of from the top.  I theorized that the full sweep area might be considered as clickable--but that had no impact--the clicks still are only available at the top of the screen.

Comment: After days of painful discovery I've come to learn that TranslateAnimation only moves where the View is *displayed* but NOT where the view is actually located. I.e., the Views were actually located at the upper left of screen although they *appear* at the bottom. (Editorial comment: This is a bizarre implementation but that's how Android's developers did it.)  To solve the problem I completely eliminated TranslateAnimation and used the View's .animate method instead. It actually moves the View's position and is far easier to use.  A single line of code does all the work. I highly recommend it.

Comment: You should post what you did as an answer and accept it.